# Is there a command to turn off the power supply to a specific USB device in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I would like to turn off the power supply to a specific USB device from the program and also disconnect the communication, is there such a command?

Answer (score 0):

The extent of USB Power Management is to allow devices to be turned off to save battery power.

This happens under the control of Device Manager.

That control does not go down to the program level.

So having further researched USB power management and to the best of my knowledge, a program cannot turn off a specific USB device.